# How to know which program is modifying iptables?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall

I noticed at some random time, my iptables rules se flushed, or not matching what I set up. I'm the only user of this server, so it is not another user but it is another program I guess.

How to know what program or "something" used that iptables command ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206894/95504